# React Js App is able to fetch data from my database but is not able to display them

Tags: reactjs, .net-core

I am developing a small school project using SQL Server, .NET Core 6 and ReactJS.

I am able to establish a connection between my front and back-end because when I put a new row on my table, my front adds another column, but does not display the data (console log shows my td's and a random "EDIT/DELETE' td)

Do I have a syntax error or something? Or maybe I should approach this differently?

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Table } from 'react-bootstrap';

export class Staff extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={deps:[]}
    }

    refreshList(){
        fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API+'staff')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {this.setState({deps:data})})
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.refreshList();
    }

    componentDidUpdate(){
        this.refreshList();
    }

    render(){
        const {deps} = this.state;
        return(
            <div className='staff'>
                <Table className='mt-4' striped bordered hover size='sm'>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Id</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Surname</th>
                            <th>Rank</th>
                            <th>Birthday</th>
                            <th>DateOfJoining</th>
                            <th>OPTIONS</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {deps.map(dep => <tr key={dep.Id}>
                            <td>{dep.Id}</td>
                            <td>{dep.Name}</td>
                            <td>{dep.Surname}</td>
                            <td>{dep.Rank}</td>
                            <td>{dep.Birthday}</td>
                            <td>{dep.DateOfJoining}</td>
                            <td>EDIT / DELETE</td>
                        </tr>)}
                    </tbody>
                </Table>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

[UPDATED screenshot with improved table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8Kxi.png)

Comment: Have you tried making a "normal" table with headers instead of rows and see how that goes? `<tr>Id</tr>`?

Comment: Yeah, I fixed it a few minutes ago, wrote <tr> instead of <th> but the main problem was not fixed unfortunately

Comment: can you show the console log?

Comment: Yes, it looks like Console Log gave me an error showing me that 'Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `Staff`. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.
    at tr
    at Staff (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:728:5)
    at Routes (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:81553:5)
    at Router (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:81486:15)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:80295:5)
    at div
    at App'